# JNI library name for 64 bit architecture on linux

Tags: java, c++, c, linux, java-native-interface

I develop a JNI dynamic library for java desktop. For now it works on MacOS and Windows, but on Linux I have a weird behaviour.

I Have the library compiled for 32 and 64 bits, but when I only put the 64 bits library and I call  `System.loadLibrary (myLibrary);` it is not able to find it, but in a 32 bits architecture when I only add the 32 bits it is able to find it (I name it libMyLibrary.so).

So my question is, for 32 bits I need to name it like `libMyLibrary.so` but how it should be named the 64 bits architecture? Shall I write some code that loads the proper library depending on the architecture?

Thanks!

Comment: Name shouldn't matter. It's probably something else - you may be able to trace the problem with `strace` perhaps?

Comment: You are right, I had a very silly mistake :) thanks

Comment: What was the mistake? It might help the next person.

Comment: The mistake is that I had a wrong "if" and end up calling system.load instead of System.loadLibrary (libName);

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is to have 32 and 64 bit versions (and for other architectures) in separate directories, and make sure the java.library.path points to the right one.

Answer (score 0):

What version of library your JVM should load depends on the JVM version the code run on, as well as the os architecture. 32 bits JVM should load 32 bits library, 64 bits should load library for 64 bits.

I have Ubuntu 64 bits OS with two JVM installed. One is 64 bits

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

And another is 32 bits

```
$ /opt/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

I use the following code to load libraries for app running in different JVMs.

```
static {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Linux")) {
        if (System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("i386")) {
            System.out.println("loading i386 library");
        } else if (System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("amd64")) {
            System.out.println("loading x86_64 library");
        }
    }
}
```